# Create a View with Previous Next and Return to Parent options

Tags: views

ok so I've currently sorted this out using raw PHP and mySQL queries but it feels like a hack and I'd like to Drupalafy it if possible. not sure if it would be quicker or not, but would certainly be easier to manage in the long run.

I have a list of node thumbs on a front page, ordered into Tax based groups. Click any of these and you are taken to that nodes page and you can next/previous though all the other nodes in that Tax group. there is also a link to take you back out to the front page (of which there could be many, as this is based on a higher level tax term).

I'll try and show an example.

```
Tax top 1.
  tax sub 1
  tax sub 2
Tax top 2
  tax sub 3
  tax sub 4

nodes 1,2,3 are in Tax sub 1
nodes 7,8,9 are in Tax sub 2
nodes 4,5,6 are in Tax sub 3

Main page 1 shows nodes 1,2,3 under heading Tax Sub 1, and 7,8,9 under Tax Sub 2, 
main page 2 shows nodes 4,5,6 only under heading Tax Sub 3. 
Click though to a node say 5, and you will have a 
Next take you to node 6 
Previous to node 4 
Home/back to Main page 2.
```

hope that makes senese. you can see it in action on this site.
[www.martynazoltaszek.com](http://www.martynazoltaszek.com)

So my question is can I do this using I guess Views? I've tried but cannot elicit the control I want completely.

edit: the nodes can be in any sort order so I guess I require the nid to be carried though to the view of a single node, and from that work out what would be next previous.

Answer (score 2):

These are rough suggestions, have you tried [custom pagers](http://drupal.org/project/custom_pagers) and eventually [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) for the previous/next links ?

For the back link, you can call your views with an URL parameter and build a footer link using this parameter (somewhat do the "destination" parameter).